# Execute js function stored in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have function in collection:

```
{

  "sig" : [
  {
    "name" : "hash",
    "hash" : [
      "056781731eaf223c799bebe04c60353ea73d60cb"
    ],
    "func" : function (str) {
      return this.hash.indexOf(str) != -1;
    }
  } 
  ]
}
```

How to execute it in nodejs?

Comment: Are you asking if there is away for mongo to handle it or just run the function from that object you got ?

Comment: If you retrieved your data as `doc` then it would just be `doc.func("056781731eaf223c799bebe04c60353ea73d60cb")` just like any function. All you need are the `()` on the property, and a JavaScript engine to run it in of course, but with nodejs you already are in a JavaScript engine. If you are asking *"How is that run on the server or used in a query?"*, then outside of `$where` or `mapReduce` which of course run within an JavaScript interpreter, then you cannot use it. JavaScript code is really only useful to a JavaScript engine.

Comment: On the "server" there is likely little point since you would need to run as `.find({ "$where": "return this.func('056781731eaf223c799bebe04c60353ea73d60cb')" })` which is basically the same thing as directly doing `.find({ "hash": "056781731eaf223c799bebe04c60353ea73d60cb" })` except that `$where` is not native and will run much slower. It would only really be practical if the `func()` actually did different things in each document.

Comment: From a "client" perspective, persisting functions in storage like this is just plain "dumb". It is far more practical to keep modular functions abstracted from the data, and instead just supply the data to an `Object/Class` constructor, where the `Object/Class` actually has such methods defined. Again, JavaScript is really only useful to JavaScript. Such data is completely useless to another language client without itself launching a JavaScript interpreter instance to handle it.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I need to store function because for now I could not imagine how many different function I need. Probably later I will do as You recommend.

Comment: On NodeJs side after retrieve doc I get "func" as `Code` _bsontype